What capacity does the linked signal in Angular 19 have that the computed signal in Angular 18 lacks?
I've seen the official docs as well as a bunch of lyrical blogs. Despite that, I still can't understand what's the fuss is about. I do understand what linkedSignal and computed are. What I do not get is how they're different.
It's said that the limitation of the latter is that it's not writeable. Correct. But in what way is the former writable? We can't do linky.set("shazoo"), can we? It's only possible for it to react to a change in another signal and then, produce a recomputed value to its consumer. However, that's precisely what the other does.
Angular 18: using computed signal.
export class Angy18 {
  ...
  siggy = signal(1);
  compy = computed(() => siggy() * 2);
}

Angular 19: using linked signal.
export class Angy19 {
  ...
  siggy = signal(1);
  linky = linkedSignal({
    source: this.siggy;
    computation: () => siggy() * 2);
  });
}

To me, it appears that the only difference is the verbose multi-line syntax is required. I'm certain that the gain of linked signals lies elsewhere. What am I missing?

it is exactly for cases when you need to linky.set("shazoo"). for example you want to have a counter of clicks after the data is loaded. linky is initialized with 0 and on every click you just do linky.set(linky() + 1)

@Andrei I'm asking the FUQ here because my IDE reports an error on that syntax. Are you saying that I can do linky.set(123) even if it's a linked signal (i.e. linky = linkedSignal(1337);?

@Andrei I was just pointed out to that the acronym may be misinterpreted if unfamiliar. FUQ is shorthand for follow-up-question (c.f. FAQ, frequently-asked-question). I'm in no way being rude to you. I'm being considerately brief.   :)

The docs at your link clearly states that you can set the value of linkedSignal.


We can't do linky.set("shazoo"), can we?

We can.

To me, it appears that the only difference is the verbose multi-line
syntax is required.

By the way, the simple form is also available:
linky = linkedSignal(() => this.siggy() * 2));


I can confirm. Must be something that my mind tripped over or something... Confusion resolved and all's good now. Great point on the simple form.

The new linkedSignal serves to declare a writable local state
It is writable and also provide the previous value.
siggy = signal(1);
linky = linkedSignal({
  source: this.siggy,
  computation: (value, previous) => value * 2,
});

// setting the new value, skiping the computation
linked.set(42); 


I'm starting to see what led me astray. You mention (like in the quoted resources), that a linked signal is writable. Yet, there's no mentioning of linky.set(123) anywhere. Nor do I see that in the blogs I've seen. I interpreted it as "writable by changing the underlying source value". I'm starting to think that there is a way to assign a value overriding the current, computed one. I tried to set it as I'd do with the default signal but my IDE barked at me. How do I impose a value imperatively to replace the precalculated one, please?

Yes, you can call : set() https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-next-o9jzvv?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Yes, it works. I must have done something incredibly retarded and got the error that led me to a confused impression. I blame the computer (perfectly aware that the machine bears no responsibility in this case, hehe).
